# How to update some data in SQL server into null for Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I want to make update function in a web based system using Classic ASP to enable the user to cancel their application. I'm not using delete function because some data should be maintained, and some data will be set into NULL. This function also allow the user to choose date range in a form to delete their application.

There is no error shown but the set of data is not updated when click on cancel button in the form.

This is the code :

```
<%param="keyid=" & session("keyid")
idkehadiran=request("idkehadiran")
nokpl=request("nokpl")

set SimpanRS=server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
sql="select * from tms_kehadiran where nokpl='"&nokpl&"' and (tarikh >= '"&tarikh&"' and tarikh <= '"&hinggaTarikh&"')"
SimpanRS.open sql,connehr,3,3

while not SimpanRS.EOF
SimpanRS("alasan")=""
SimpanRS("nokpPenyelia")=""
SimpanRS("kelulusan")=null
if isnull(SimpanRS("datecreated")) then
SimpanRS("datecreated")=now
end if
SimpanRS("lastupdate")=now

SimpanRS.update
SimpanRS.movenext
wend
SimpanRS.close
set SimpanRS=nothing
%>
```

I don't what are the error with this code. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I don't offhand see anything wrong, so I'd suggest the usual debugging steps: first of all, `response.write sql` and then run that SQL statement directly - does it return the row(s) it should? If yes, then add `response.write`s in the while loop to see if it's looping - if not, then your connection string (`connehr`) might be the issue.

Comment: Another thing to check - does `,3,3` open an updateable recordset? Although if it didn't, I'd expect a runtime error on the `SimpanRS.update` line...

Comment: I'm new in Classic ASP, may I know on which part of the code that i can write response.write ? @Martha

Comment: You can use `response.write` pretty much anywhere in your code. It writes whatever you tell it to into the html of the page.

Comment: I'd write the 'response.write' code to check whether the record set is empty or not, but it do not show anything. I put the code before line 'while not SImpanRS.EOF'

Answer (score -1):

Instead of looping the RS. You should use GetRows().

After that you can update the data in the SQL server while looping the array.

Comment: And how exactly do you propose he update the data in SQL server *without* looping the RS?

Comment: How to do the GetRows()?